# Debug view hierarchy does not render UI

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

i'm trying to use the view hierarchy feature on xcode 6 to see the draggable layout of my app, but all i get is a blank area where it should be.

after trying out lots of suggestions from SO and other places, nothing works.

I have had the sim running with or without break points, different sim devices, different apps, but nothing works.

I know you're just supposed to click on the button while the app is being simulated and it's supposed to pop up, but when i do it the main interface with the button and options load along with all the elements in the debug navigator. just not the 3d UI itself.

thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1):

You can click in that view and drag by holding down the left mouse button. This gives you the 3D view.

Comment: there's actually no images at all, so no views for me to click. i've seen screenshots/ videos of the the center with the views, but mine is just blank. however, i know it knows something should be there because data gets loaded in the side panes.

Comment: Same here, all the data is on the side panes but my 3D UI is empty.
Worst is, this works fine at work on my mac, and not on my VM at home

Comment: Using hackintosh here, working with 2 ATI cards I've tested with, not working with 2 nVidia cards..

Answer (score 1):

It's not a fix, but when I had this issue I restarted Xcode and tried again a few more times it eventually worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a recent issue as well which I've run into. When I press the button, I get an assertion failure:

> Assertion failure in -[UITextView _firstBaselineOffsetFromTop]

There's an [OpenRadar here](https://openradar.appspot.com/25311044) with a workaround which worked for me of attaching a "useless" constraint" in ViewController.m:

```
if ([NSLayoutConstraint respondsToSelector:@selector(activateConstraints:)]) {
    TEXTVIEWNAME.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[TEXTVIEWNAME]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(TEXTVIEWNAME)]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After clicking "Debug View Hierarchy" button, you are on the blank white screen.

Click on thread option depicted in below image, list will open, select any option from list, and again click on "Debug View Hierarchy" button.
Screen will render.

This is what works for me.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really old now, but this is still occurring for me.  At first, I only saw a spinner when clicking on the debug view hierarchy.  But, when I tried the steps above to click on my equivalent to the "0 mach_msg_trap" above, and then back on the debug view hierachy, the spinner went away.  This was an improvement since I was not just staring at a spinner now that seemed to never stop spinning no matter how long I waited ( 20 minutes for example ).  However, at this step now, the screen is blank, just like stanley mentioned above.  So, I still cannot see any useful debug information.

One thing I will note is that what I am trying to view is inside a webview.  Webviews cause our xcuitests lots of problems, that we eventually do solve.  But, they do not play as nicely as other objects.  I mention the webview because of this just in case it's the actual reason I am not seeing anything displayed in the debug view hierachy.