# Xcode view hierarchy debugging not showing the content

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using Xcode 10.1 now, running on real device.

It's weird that I can't capture 'some' of my projects view hierarchy content in Xcode.

All view modes I tried changed nothing

[image]

It always shows like wireframes without content as below

[image: view without content]

selected 'Wireframes' view mode does noting but just highlight the frame

[image: wireframe mode]

Any idea to do with it?

Comment: I found an idea from this post, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48807207/5589964. Can you try it

Comment: @ChuongTran Thank you, but not work for me. :(

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: I am facing this issue in XCode 11.3.1. Have you found solution?